# How to populate a nested list of objects in C#

Tags: c#, nested, initialization, nested-lists, object-oriented-analysis

I have a class as shown below:

```
public class Par
    {
        public string id { get { return id; } set { id = value; } }
        public Int32 num { get { return num; } set { num = value; } }
}
```

Now I make a class named "Msg" which has a nested list of Par objects

```
public class Msg 
    {
        private Int32 mid; 
        private Int32 mnum; 
        public List<Par> pList; //list of Par objects

        //constructor of Msg
        public Msg(Int32 mid, Int32 mnum)
        {
            this.mid = mid;
            this.mnum = mnum;
            this.pList = new List<Par>();
        }
  
public void add_ParObject_To_pList(Par obj) 
        {
            pList.Add(obj);
        }
```

In the main method, I am looping through each row of my text file and extracting its contents using a foreach loop

```
foreach (string line in lines)
//I have instantiated a list of Msg objects named "MList"
    List<Msg> MList = new List<Msg>();

    //my code to extract data from each line 

    Par pobj = new Par(id, num); //instantiating a Par object 

    //code to check within MList if there exists a Msg object with extracted mid and mnum values from file. If not, then new Msg object must be added to this list passing in this mid and mnum.
    MList.Add(new Msg(mid, mnum));
```

Question:
How do I call and populate the nested "pList"  (list of Par objects containing id and num), which belongs to the Msg object in this foreach loop?

Also, here is sample data from my text file:

| mid | mnum | id | num |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 | 1000 | 200 |
| 1 | 10 | 2000 | 201 |
| 2 | 20 | 1000 | 101 |
| 2 | 20 | 2000 | 102 |

The objective is that the code should arrange the data in the MList (list of Msg objects) as below (based on the sample data provided):

> msglist[0] -> 1,       10 pList[0]: 1000  200,
> pList[1]: 2000  201

> msglist[1] -> 2,       20 pList[0]: 1000  101,
> pList[1]: 2000  102

I would greatly appreciate any suggestions/input. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why did you add the C language tag for your C# question? Please don't add unrelated or even *wrong* tags.

Comment: Why do you create the list _inside_ of your loop? It will never hold more then 1 item that way as it get's recreated on the start of the loop every time!

Comment: You need to add your PAR's to your MSGs. If they are in order you can simply read all PARs belonging to the current MSG and do a `MList.Last().add_ParObject_To_pList(pobj)` - or you look up the correct MSG-Obj in your MList (f.e. Linq, Where, based on its ID - may need using System.Linq)  and add it to that. Fix the errors in the creation logic first. Then research  `c# Find element in list using linq by id site:stackoverflow.com` via google - should give you plenty results (maybe substitute _id_ by _attribute_)

Comment: I don't think you designed this properly. The text file has 4 fields. Your class `Par`, should therefore also have 4 fields. Once it is created, you can use Linq to pull out items that match whatever condition you need when you want to make a message.

Comment: @dmedine  the data from the text file is split over 2 classes that together have all the needed fields?

Comment: You will get a  StackOverflowException if you access a property of your `Par` class. Use private fields for your properties or even better auto properties.

Comment: @PatrickArtner right, but the rows of the text file have 1 column called `mid`, 1 called `mnum`, 1 called `id` and 1 called `num`. The structure of the code is a class with 1 field called `mid`, 1 called `mnum`, and 1 `List` of a objects whose class contains 1 field called `id` and 1 field called `num`. To me, anyway, that is not a logical way to represent the structure of the text file in a C# program.

Comment: dmedine, it's a typical flat file representation of a 1:M relationship that needs restoring to 1:M...

Comment: @CaiusJard, To me mixing up the structure of the data with an eye to how the data is to be  used by a client is not good design practice.

Answer (score 1):

Keep a dictionary of Msg as you parse the file, not a List; Dictionary is fast for lookups and you're going to be doing a lookup for every line

```
var msgs = new Dictionary<string, Msg>();

foreach(var line in File.ReadAllLines("path to file"){

  //code to get the column values from line here blah blah
  var mid = ...
  var mnum = ...

  //msg caching logic 

  if(!msgs.ContainsKey(mid))
    msgs[mid] = new Msg(mid, mnum);

  var p = new Par(...)

  msgs[mid].pList.Add(p);

}
```

You can either keep the dictionary and work with it or if you want all the Msg in a list/array/enumerable etc, you can access the dictionary's `.Values` property

Please name `pList` -> `PList` and `add_ParObject_To_pList` -> `AddParObjectToPList` (or discard the method; the list is public). In c# PublicPropertiesAndMethodsArePascalCase